# Simplify Γ(2α) in Γ(α) terms

Tags: gamma-function

I need to simplify Γ(2α) in Γ(α) terms where α is a real number greater than 1. (I need to cancel out Γ( . ) terms in a simplification). Shall accept a product term with Γ(α), like (2α - 1)*...*α*Γ(α). Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: So you want help proving that $\Gamma(2\alpha)=(2\alpha-1)\cdots\alpha\Gamma(\alpha)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I need to cancel out Γ( . ) terms in a simplification

Comment: @Arthur Of course yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the product
$$
(2\alpha-1)\cdots\alpha\Gamma(\alpha)
$$
and work your way from the right. The two rightmost terms are $\alpha\Gamma(\alpha)$. By the defining property of the $\Gamma$ function, this is equal to $\Gamma(\alpha+1)$.

Write down the total product after this simplification. What are the two rightmost terms? Can that be simplified? What is the resulting total product? Can *that* be simplified? How far can you keep going? What's the end result?

PS. This does, of course, assume that $\alpha$ is a positive integer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in my situation, α is a real number which is greater than 1.  It's known that  Γ(α+1) = αΓ(α) works for any α, either it's positive integer valued or positive real valued. The following link provides the formula. (page 2 / 20 ) https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/link/gammaFunction.pdf

Comment: (2α−1)(2α−2)(2α−3)⋯(α+2)(α+1)αΓ(α) makes no sense how it works for a real valued α

Comment: @DoviniJayasinghe Yes, that relation still holds for any valid input. But if $\alpha$ is not a natural number, then note that the identity we're after is actually of the form $\Gamma(2\alpha)=(2\alpha-1)\cdots(2\alpha-n)\Gamma(2\alpha-n)$. The last term here won't be the $\alpha$ you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment